# Need a 3ms delay after connecting to MySQL in Dart to successfully query. Why?

Tags: mysql, dart, async-await, database-connection

Hello Stack Overflow community!

I've encountered a peculiar issue when working with MySQL in Dart. When I try to query the database immediately after establishing a connection, I get an empty result. However, if I add a delay of 3ms before making the query, everything works as expected.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  final settings = ConnectionSettings(
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    db: 'base_mysql',
  );

  try {
    final MySqlConnection connection = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
    
    // Introducing a short delay before querying
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3));
    
    final results = await connection.query('SHOW TABLES');
    for (var row in results) {
      final tableName = row.values?.first;
      if (tableName != null) {
        print('Table Name: $tableName');
      }
    }

    await connection.close();

  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

Without this 3ms delay, the first query returns an empty result. The MySQL logs during this process show:

```
2023-10-02T10:24:48.514849Z    43 Connect   root@[client-ip] on base_mysql using TCP/IP
2023-10-02T10:24:48.519878Z    43 Query SHOW TABLES
2023-10-02T10:24:48.539763Z    43 Quit
```

I'm curious as to why this might be happening. Has anyone faced a similar issue? I'd appreciate any insights or explanations for this behavior.

Comment: await is asynchron, what you need is a synchron call

Comment: I understand that using await makes the operation asynchronous, and based on the recommendation, I should use a synchronous call. However, I'm having difficulty understanding how to correctly implement this in my specific situation. Could @nbk please provide a code example or guide me on how to convert my asynchronous call into a synchronous one in Dart?

Answer (score 0):

We use the followiong solution.
If an error occurs, it is able to reset the connection and create a new one.
The sites have been working without problems for months.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

import 'yaml_config.dart';

Completer<MySqlConnection>? _connectionCompleter;

Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
  try {
    if (_connectionCompleter == null) {
      return _createConnection();
    } else {
      final connection = await _connectionCompleter!.future;
      await connection.query('SELECT 1');
      return connection;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    const knownMessages = [
      'Cannot write to socket, it is closed',
      'Socket has been closed',
    ];
    final message = '$e';
    for (final knownMessage in knownMessages) {
      if (message.contains(knownMessage)) {
        return _createConnection();
      }
    }

    rethrow;
  }
}

Future<MySqlConnection> _connect() async {
  final config = yamlConfig('config.yaml');
  final settings = ConnectionSettings(
      host: config.read('database.host'),
      port: config.read('database.port'),
      user: config.read('database.user'),
      password: config.read('database.password'),
      db: config.read('database.database'));
  final result = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  return result;
}

Future<MySqlConnection> _createConnection() async {
  final completer = Completer<MySqlConnection>();
  _connectionCompleter = completer;
  try {
    final connection = await _connect();
    completer.complete(connection);
  } catch (e, s) {
    completer.completeError(e, s);
    _connectionCompleter = null;
    rethrow;
  }

  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: The issue still persists. If I make a single SHOW TABLES query, I don't get a response. However, if I make two consecutive SHOW TABLES queries or introduce a delay before making the query, I receive the expected response.

Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to address this without resorting to the aforementioned workarounds?